# how to load test wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, load-testing

How I can test the performance of my site. I need to check either more than 400 users can access the site at a same time and purchase one product. Need to test one special product to be sold. Which may be more than 500 users will buy at once.
How I can simulate the transactions in order to load test the site.

Answer (score 0):

Handling number of users by website not depends on WordPress but it depends on which server(web hosting) you are using.

While what depends on WordPress is website performance. The more number of extra plugins, not well developed theme and ignored WP standards can make site performance slow.

You can check your website performance at:

- [Google insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)
- [GT Metrix](https://gtmetrix.com/)
- [Pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com/)

Here is the link for your reference to send test traffic to your website: 
[Test traffic](https://growtraffic.com/blog/2015/01/top-10-traffic-generator-applications-web)
Hope this helps.

Comment: You can also try this way [Load Speed](https://wpspeedmatters.com/how-to-load-test-a-wordpress-website/)

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to create an automated load test script either in Jmeter or any other tool and you can generate as much load you want.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [A Beginner’s Guide to Load Testing WordPress Sites](https://torquemag.io/2016/10/load-testing-wordpress-sites/):

1. Check Your WordPress And Front End Setup Before Testing (use [GTmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/), [PageSpeed insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) and [P3 plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/) to check whether your frontend part is up-to-speed
2. Document And Tune Your Back End Stack: you need to ensure that all the infrastructure is ready for high loads: operating system, web server, database, load balancer, etc. - all of them needs to be [tuned for the high performance](https://stackify.com/web-performance-optimization/)
3. Exploring DIY Load Testing Options. Choose a [load testing tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use/) and implement  the real life usage of your application. Once you do this you can replay the test with increased number of users and explore the metrics